# add column to existing query with GROUP BY

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I have got little issue, I'm trying to put another column klisluz.cena to existing query but its giving me errors that: Column klisluz.cena in command SELECT isnt correct, because its not in GROUP BY, but when I insert it in GROUP BY it throws the same error. Where should I put it ?

Thanks in advance. this is the query:

```
 string sQuery = string.Format("SELECT zajsluz.akce,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet,klisluz.cena,klisluz.subkey,zajsluz.ID FROM zajsluz LEFT JOIN klisluz ON zajsluz.ID=klisluz.IDzajsluz WHERE zajsluz.akce= '{0}' and ISNULL(klisluz.subkey, '" + vyberradek + "') = '" + vyberradek + "' GROUP BY klisluz.subkey,zajsluz.akce,zajsluz.text,klisluz.pocet,zajsluz.ID", sZakce);
```

Comment: You really don't have to provide the variable, just TSQL code. That way it would be easier to properly format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column "cena" is a numeric price value, then you could perform an Aggregate Function on it.

You could try to use the MAX(klisluz.cena) to get the maximum value, or SUM(..) to get a sum any other one that could apply to this column type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx

Answer (score 2):

klisluz.cena is not in the group by.